# Fetching in Firebase Realtime Database with React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an error when fetching data on firebase realtime database with react js hook. When i lopping data with map, error is coming "is undefined" but i saw on the console log data is success.

I think the error because looping code execute before fetching finish

this is fetch code

```
    const [firebaseDb, setFirebaseDb] = useState(database);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const getData = async () =>{
        try {
            const dbRef = firebaseDb;
            let snapshot = await get(child(dbRef, `menu`))
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log(snapshot.val());
                setData(snapshot.val());
                setLoading(false);
            } else {
                setData({});
                setLoading(false);
                console.log("No data available");
            }
        } catch(e){
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(e.message);
                        
        }        
        
    } 

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        getData()
    }, []);
```

this is lopping code

```
            {
                loading ? (
                    <Row><p>Loading ... !</p></Row>

                ) : (
                        <Row>
                            {
                                data.appetizer.map((apper, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Col key={index} lg='6' className="p-3">
                                            <div className="menu-list p-3">
                                                <h5>{apper.name}</h5>
                                                <h4>{apper.price}k</h4>
                                                <p className="mb-0">{apper.desc}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </Col>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </Row>
                    )

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` variable is an array at initial, so it doesnt has `appetizer` attribute. Use `data.map(...)` instead. ( try to pass to `setData` with an array )

Of course rendering will always execute before fetching finish. All you need is checking `typeof data.length > 0`   before render mapping ---- or just set initial value of `loading` into true.

It should be something like this:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

Or

```
loading || data.length === 0 ? (
    <Row><p>Loading ... !</p></Row>
)
```